# difference between sequence and series of functions regarding uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Those two confuses me. Could anyone please explain the main differences?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The main differences between what?

Comment: Sorry i wasnt specific enough. When proving something is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Any sequence can be written as a series and vice versa (assuming the values are in a vector space or some other space which allows adding/substracting the elements), e.g. $a_k = \sum^k_l b_l$ and $c_i = \sum^i_k (c_k-c_{k-1})$. You may simply observe things easier in one or the other representation. Of course this applies to functions, too.

Answer (score 0):

Series of functions are specific type of a sequential functions! So, we can see a serie of functions as a sequence of functions: Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infinit f_n(x)$ be the serie. Than the sequence $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$ representes the same serie. So, while serie and sequence are same, than the uniform continuity states same for both cases.